# iOS animation using spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to create an animation on my iOS application using spritekit.

so far the code that i have done for this is

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class TygaScene: SKScene {

    var tygaFrames: [SKTexture]?       // array of images

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(size: CGSize) {  // init function then set size
        super.init(size: size)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white   // setting colour to background 

        var frames:[SKTexture] = []    // create place holder for texture to initialise

        let tygaAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "tyga")

        for index in 1...5 {    // adding all images from folder
            let textureName = "tyga_\(index)"  // naming the first bit of the file
            let texture =  tygaAtlas.textureNamed(textureName)
            frames.append(texture)
        }
        self.tygaFrames = frames


    }


    func moveTyga() {
        let texture = self.tygaFrames![0]
        let tyga = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

        tyga.size = CGSize(width: 280, height: 280)

        let randometygaYPositionGenerator = GKRandomDistribution(lowestValue: 50, highestValue: Int(self.frame.size.height))
        let yPosition = CGFloat(randometygaYPositionGenerator.nextInt())

        let rightToLeft = arc4random() % 2 == 0

        let xPosition = rightToLeft ? self.frame.size.width + tyga.size.width / 2 : -tyga.size.width / 2

        tyga.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)

        if rightToLeft {
            tyga.xScale = -1
        }
        self.addChild(tyga)

        tyga.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: self.tygaFrames!, timePerFrame: 0.05, resize: false, restore: true)))



        var distanceToCover = self.frame.size.width + tyga.size.width
        if rightToLeft {
            distanceToCover += -1
        }

        let time = TimeInterval(abs(distanceToCover/140))

        let moveAction = SKAction.run {
            tyga.removeAllActions ()
            tyga.removeFromParent()

        }
        let allActions = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, removeAction])

        tyga.run(allActions)

        } 

    }
```

The part that is giving an error is the line:

```
let allActions = SKAction.sequence([moveAction, removeAction])            
    tyga.run(allActions)            
}
```

could you please advise me on how i could overcome this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Where is removeAction declared? and what is it?

Comment: Exactly as Ron mentioned, you are missing the declaration for `removeAction`, therefore you are probably getting a compiler error on that line. However, even if you fix that compiler error, your `SKAction` sequence starts with a call to `removeAllActions()`, followed by `removeFromParent()` which would just remove your node from the scene without anything happening.